# Centos 6 - join AD domain, authenticate using another trusted domain

Tags: centos, cross-domain, rhel6, trust

I have 2 domains, lets call them domain X.dom and Y.dom, and they have trust between them.

On domain X.dom I have a security group, inside of which has members of Y.dom using this group. I successfully  managed to connect to Centos 7 machines (joined to X.dom). So an AD user on Y.dom can connect to a Centos 7 machine with his creds (using winbind,realmd). I configured this group on pam_winbind.conf using "require_membership_of".

This setup works perfectly, but I failed to do the same for Centos 6.

First of all, I did manage to join the Centos 6 machines to X.dom but the machine doesn't recognize Y.dom users.

Is it even possible to pull it on Centos 6?

If so, can you point me to the right direction?

Thanks!